# Login with facebook in ASP.NET MVC4 Razaor Engine

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, entity-framework-5

Could any one help me how can I do  login functionality with facebook login page in my  MVC4 Internet application.
Thanks in advance

Comment: [login facebook asp.net mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc)

Comment: Did you try google? here is a [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc) on how to use openauth.